# Do I need a transit visa to fly from a schegen country via London to travel to USA?

Tags: transit, transit-visas

I am traveling from Prague to Boston and have a layover in London to change my flight and duration between flight is 2 hours. I hold a valid H1b visa of USA. Am I required to obtain a transit visa?